# Возможно ли сделать на Android службу так что бы она не закрывалась не при каких условиях

Tags: android

Бъюсь уже вторую неделю и не могу реализовать задачу. Задача сделать обратный отчет до начала урока и перемены в школе. Пробовал службу естественно она благополучно погибает через некоторое время. Пробовал foreground службу она так же благополучно помирает. Пробовал алам менеджеры, они слишком неточные и получается что один аларм заводит сразу другой, соответственно не сработает 1 и все, приложение встало. Пробовал Wokr еры. Пробовал бродкаст ресиверы,пробовал по моему ужэ все что только можно. Итог 1 приложение через некоторое время благополучно закрывается. Подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону капнуть. И реально ли это вообще? Ведь тот же будильник в телефоне работает отлично как часы, те же ватсапы то же работают, а значит они на фоне там ждут сообщения. Проверял на физическом устройстве honor. На эмуляторах оно работает более надежно в целом получилось только пару раз словить момент что приложение закрылось.

Comment: Можно, она должна обновлять постоянно свой notification

Comment: я делаю отсчет, раз в  секунду и вывожу в notification и по сути обновляю раз в секунду notification. Но оно все равно в какой то момент умирает

Comment: по поводу неточных алармов, https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#doze-and-standby (стоит прочитать всю страницу и ещё это https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby), используйте setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(), чтобы аларм не откладывался до выхода телефона из doze мода. Если нужно отображать нотификацию, то используйте foreground service + START_STICKY